Msgraph python sdk - add top query parameter required function missing
Currently creating a small cloud function that will pull messages in from an outlook inbox using the microsftgraph sdk for python. I am trying to make it so the app will pull as many messages as possible in the first request, and the way to do this seems to be by adding a 'top' query parameter and setting it to 1000 - the max. However the examples provided to achieve this seem to use a function which does not exist - MessagesRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration. Does anyone have any solutions or have I missed something?
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python/blob/main/docs/general_samples.md
Example code I am using
The file where the function should be:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python/blob/main/msgraph/generated/users/item/messages/messages_request_builder.py
I have not tried anything yet, I am aware I can probably just send the request myself rather than using the client library but would ideally like a way to get it working.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think it was just waiting on a documentation update, got it working like so:
from kiota_abstractions.base_request_configuration import RequestConfiguration

query_params= MessageRequestBuilder.MessageRequestBuilderGetQueryParams(top=1000)
request_config= RequestConfiguration(query_parameters=query_params)

SomeProcess.get(request_configuration=request_config)

